# Input Range Slider in java

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, slider, oracle-adf

Has anyone worked with Input Range Slider RichInputRangeSlider? I am looking for some examples to get started for vertical input range.
I looked into this one as well:
[Some explanation about it](http://opreview.blogspot.ca/2012/10/adf-using-input-range-slider.html)

[RichInputRangeSlider](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/apirefs.1111/e12419/tagdoc/af_inputRangeSlider.html)

[image]
I am looking for some code that I can actually test and learn how to work with this slider. If you have any other suggestions please let me know.

[image]

Comment: I added another picture which i got from here : https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/jide_jfreechart_javafx_and_enterprise

Comment: It is not JavaFX related question. Am I right?

Comment: Is it not related to ADF? The RichInputRangeSlider is from ADF.

Answer (score 0):

What is it you are looking for? The documentation page for  provides a documentation on how to use it. You need to have a JSP which declares the component:

```
<af:inputRangeSlider label="Horizontal Slider" 
                 minorIncrement="1" 
                 majorIncrement="5" 
                 minimumIncrement="1" 
                 minimum="0" 
                 maximum="10" 
                 id="rs1" 
                 value="#{viewScope.myBean.rangeValue}" />
```

And then a managed bean which tracks the value of the inputRangeSlider which would be something like:

```
class MyManagedBean{
  int rangeValue;

  public int getRangeValue(){
    return rangeValue;
  }
  public void setRangeValue(int rangeValue){
    this.rangeValue = rangeValue;
  }
}
```

And in the adfc-config.xml file you have to declare this bean at the viewScope and then use it.